# Sampling weights in R with survey package

Tags: r, sampling, survey

I am using a large, complex dataset for my analysis, where sampling weights should be used for the analysis to get more unverserable results. The study is the [Add Health data](https://addhealth.cpc.unc.edu/), of which I am using two measurement time points (baseline and wave4). Here it is unclear to me how I can include two sample weights (for baseline and wave4) in order to calculate my multilevel model later? I have now decided to use the `svydesign()` function from the `survey` package.

My sample weight for baseline is weight_wave1, my sample weight for wave4 is weight_wave4.

```
load(data_total)
des_wave1 <-svydesign(id=~BA_identify_numb_integer, 
                      strata=~NULL,
                      weights=weight_wave1,
                      data=data_total)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have good news and bad news.

The good news: there's no problem with including two weights.  Just write your data in 'long' format, so that an individual's record for baseline and for wave 4 are in separate records (with an id variable to link them).  Then you can use the baseline weight for the baseline data and the wave 4 weight for the wave 4 data.

Or, if wave 4 is a strict subset of baseline, just use the wave 4 weights and drop the baseline records for people who don't have wave 4.

The bad news: multilevel models for complex survey data are not entirely straightforward.  You likely want to ask on `stats.stackexchange` about how to fit your multilevel model taking weights into account.